# Buddypress translation with language switcher from PolyLang plugin

Tags: string, wordpress, translation, profile, buddypress

I have a problem regarding translating BuddyPress strings inside the profile page.
I know that I can insert the translations in the (.pot) file,but my question is that after translating them into the needed language, how can I show this new translated profile page?

Note: I am using PolyLang translation plugin, and it provides a language switcher for the website and it works very well, but the BP profile page remains in original English language without changing!

Regards and Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Do you end up with a .mo file? If not then you'll need to investigate how you can generate one from the .pot

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I thought that nobody replied ever! thanks for reply .... I have .po and .mo files, how can I display them !?